# Estimating Object Size Based on Vertical Distance

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have a vertical distance of 3 meters between the shooting plane and the camera.

At this time, when an object appears on the shooting plane from the camera, I want to get the size of the object, please tell me how to do it.

I currently have a camera set up at a vertical distance of 3 meters with various objects printed on a white wall.

I know the lens used in the camera, sensor specs, etc.